# Solving $x = c\times \ln(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

How to solve $x = c\times \ln(x)$ where c is some constant? I'm trying to figure out how to solve the prime number theorem for x, given the number of primes.

Comment: it is $x= -c W\left(-\frac{1}{c}\right)$

Comment: The above comment is referring to [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: So there is no simpler way to solve this besides graphing it? By simpler, I mean something less advanced, because I have not learned about the Lambert's W function

Comment: The $W$ function is like a variation on the log function. The log function is the inverse of $e^x$; the W function is the inverse of $xe^x$.

Answer (score 4):

That equation cannot be solved in terms of the most elementary functions. The Lambert W function can be used for that (though probably your calculator does not include it).

Another way is iteratively (assuming $c>3$) : $x_{n+1} = c \ln(x_{n})$, starting with $x_0=c$.
Or, much more quickly ([Newton–Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) ) $$x_{n+1} =   \frac{\ln (x_{n})-1}{1/c-1/x_n}$$ starting with $x_0=c \ln(c)$